# Can I run irfanview in MATLAB and batch/convert images?

Tags: matlab, irfanview

I have a set of images (> 500) and I want to convert them to  `.PGM` format.
Is there some way to do it from a `.m` file?

Best regards!

**UPDATE 06/09/2016**

I found the following [link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/iviewcli.txt), where IRFANVIEW commands to appear, but I have no experience running external commands from matlab. I used the following script:

```
dir_irfanview=('C:\Program Files (x86)\IrfanView\i_view32.exe');
cmd ='filelist=c:\v\list.txt /convert= c:\vc\*.pgm';
cmd2 = [cmd,dir_irfanview];
system(cmd2);
```

and I get the following error:

*"filelist" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
program or batch file.*

Note that I used the "*i_view32.exe filelist=c:\v\list.txt /convert= c:\vc*.pgm*" command in DOS and no problems.

some guidance?

Comment: What is wrong with the batch conversion option that IrfanView has itself?

Comment: Yes use [system](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) to run programs outside matlab.

Comment: I use a face recognition method (.bat in C / C ++) which has problems with the images created in matlab (image header), so to use the method I require  transform .pgm to .pgm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Jørgen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266588/can-i-run-irfanview-in-matlab-and-batch-convert-images#comment65869662_39266588) suggested, you can use `system()` to call irfanview to convert.

Alternatively, you can use `imread` and `imwrite` in a loop to do the job in a more "matlab"-ish way

```
fls = dir('/path/to/images/*');
for ii=1:numel(fls)
    if fls(ii).isdir
        continue; 
    end
    [pth fn ext] = fileparts(fls(ii).name);
    img = imread(fullfile('/path/to/images',fls(ii).name));
    imwrite(img, fullfile('/path/to/images',[fn, '.pgm']));
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, had read about the command system(), I need information to access some specific options program (example: in Irfanview by pressing 'B' leads to the conversion option). Regards!